# How can I register customized user model in Django admin site?

Tags: django

I customized my own user `model`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', '남'),
    ('F', '여'),
)


class ChachaUser(AbstractUser):
    birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='M')

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email', ]
```

And I made `admin.py` :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from users.models import ChachaUser

admin.site.register(ChachaUser)
```

And do `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. It doens't occur any error.

But `Admin` site doesn't show any User model infos :
[image]

Did I make any mistake? Need helps.

Comment: Have you restarted the your web server, that serves Django?

Comment: agree, try to restart the server. And don't forget to update AUTH_USER_MODEL var to specify a new user model

Comment: Which app is the `ChachaUser` model in? Did you remember to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS`?